# Symfony 2 bug generating wrong cache file

Tags: symfony

I've a serious problem with a Symfony 2.0.16 installation. Cache file generated for a simple service is wrong.

One service `replacer.factory`, sort of factory one. I'll show only a simplified version:

```php
/**
 * @DI\Service("replacer.factory")
 */
class ReplacerFactory
{

    /**
     * @DI\InjectParams({"container" = @DI\Inject("service_container")})
     */
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getReplacer($object)
    {
        $replacer = new NewsletterReplacer($this->container);

        // Return the instance of NewsletterReplacer class
        return $replacer->setInstance($object);
    }

}
```

And this is the instance returned, again a bit simplified:

```php
class NewsletterReplacer
{

    private $container;

    private $instance;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function setInstance(Newsletter $newsletter)
    {
        $this->instance = $newsletter;
    }
}
```

For some reason, **cache file generated is completely wrong**.

In fact, this is part of `appDevProjectContainer.php` file, after the command `php app/console cache:clear --env=dev --no-debug`:

```php
protected function getReplacer_FactoryService()
{
    return $this->services['replacer.factory']
        = new \Acme\HelloBundle\Service\Replacer\NewsletterReplacer();
}
```

It should be instead:

```php
protected function getReplacer_FactoryService()
{
    return $this->services['replacer.factory']
        = new \Acme\HelloBundle\Service\Replacer\ReplacerFactory($this);
}
```

So, what's wrong and how can i solve it?

Comment: are you sure that's wrong? `getReplacer_FactoryService()` sounds like it **should** be returning a factory, which it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a PHP bug with annotation along with JMSDiExtraBundle, see [this issue](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/issues/55). Solved updating PHP 5.3.3-7.